# How can I merge partitions in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, unallocated, merge

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 and it's my first time I am using Ubuntu. I installed it using 50 GB space first because I had Windows 7 installed previously and thought that i will make it duel boot but due to OEM BIOS restriction I could not do that and lost Windows 7 now. I formatted the drive on which Windows 7 was there. Now I have this space left and I want to use that 220 GB unallocated space and merge in swap and extended partitions. I have Gparted installed.

[image]

I am not aware of it how to do it. Please suggest. Step by step guidance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get use to command line. Take advantage and explore `fdisk` command.
You need to use sudo for this.

Or

I suggest the application `gparted`. You may have to install it from the Ubuntu repository or Software Center. It will give you user friendly interface that will make things easy for you.

Note- If any of the partitions that you want to merge is in use, you will have to do it from live DVD/USB using GParted

Comment: If any of the partitions that you want to merge is in use, you will have to do it from live DVD/USB using GParted.

Comment: i will add it to my answer.